# how to show default list in spinner in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Recently I developed one app. In this, The values are retrieved from the MySQL data base into the spinner. The problem is that it crashes when internet is not present. My intention is, if the internet is not present show default values. Otherwise if the internet is available show the values from MySQL database.

```
public class MilkProduction extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener{
    private EditText quantity;
    private Button submit, cancel;
    private TextView date_time;
    Calendar calander;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    String time;
    private AutoCompleteTextView animal_id;
    private List<Animal> fruits ;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    private Spinner spinner1;
    private String shift_id;
    private String product;
     String shiftid="",intime="",outtime="";
    //JSON Array
    private JSONArray result;
    //An ArrayList for Spinner Items
    private ArrayList<String> students;
private  Animal item ;
    private Animal animal=new Animal();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.milk_production);

        animal_id = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edt_animal_id);
        quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_milkproduction_quan);
        date_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_timt_date_year);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_prodc_submit);


        calander = Calendar.getInstance();
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        time = simpleDateFormat.format(calander.getTime());
        date_time.setText(time);
        date_time.setTextSize(15);

        students = new ArrayList<String>();

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());


        //Calling the method that will fetch data
        proautocomplete();

        prodropdown();

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();


                // check for Internet status
                if (isInternetPresent) {

                     insertUser();
                   }
               else{

                    showAlertDialog(MilkProduction.this, "Internet not available",
                            "Internet is not available in this device", false);
                }
            }
        });

 }

    private void prodropdown() {
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                .build(); //Finally building the adapter

        //Creating object for our interface
        AnimalAPI api = adapter.create(AnimalAPI.class);
        api.insertUser1( new Callback<Response>() {


            @Override
            public void success(Response response, Response response2) {

               String detailsString = Others.getStringFromRetrofitResponse(response);


                try {

                    //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                    JSONObject  j = new JSONObject(detailsString);

                    //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                    result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                    //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                    getStudents(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }




            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getStudents(JSONArray j) {

        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                students.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_USERNAME));



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
        spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MilkProduction.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students));

    }



    //Method to get student name of a particular position
    private String getShiftid(int position){
        String name="";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);

            //Fetching name from that object
         //   name = json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);

            name = animal.setShiftid(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return name;
    }

    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()
    private String getIntime(int position){
        String course="";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
         //   course = json.getString(Config.TAG_COURSE);

            course= animal.setIntime(json.getString(Config.TAG_COURSE));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return course;
    }

    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()
    private String getOuttime(int position){
        String session="";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
          //  session = json.getString(Config.TAG_SESSION);

            session=  animal.setOuttime(json.getString(Config.TAG_SESSION));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return session;
    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String spin = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item

        shiftid=(getShiftid(position));
        intime=(getIntime(position));
        outtime=(getOuttime(position));



    }



    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          shiftid="";
           intime="";
          outtime="";

    }


    private void insertUser() {
//While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading","Please wait...",false,false);

        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                .build(); //Finally building the adapter

        //Creating object for our interface
        AnimalAPI api = adapter.create(AnimalAPI.class);


        api.insertUser(
                animal_id.getText().toString(),
                quantity.getText().toString(),
                date_time.getText().toString(),

                spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                " ",
                shiftid,
                intime,
                outtime,
                new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                        //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Creating a bufferedreader object
                        BufferedReader reader = null;

                        //An string to store output from the server
                        String output = "";

                        try {
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                            //Reading the output in the string
                            output = reader.readLine();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //Displaying the output as a toast
                        Toast.makeText(MilkProduction.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MilkProduction.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

        );

    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mm"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dairy_layout_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/corner3"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="13dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Milk Production"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="#023e64"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="13dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_animal_shfit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shift                       : "
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:prompt="@string/shift_prompt"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                android:entries="@array/android_dropdown_arrays1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="13dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_animal_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Animal                   : "
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:gravity="left"
                />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/edt_animal_id"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/corner1"
                android:layout_weight="0.60"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="">

            </AutoCompleteTextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="13dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_milk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Quantity                 : "
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:gravity="left"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_milkproduction_quan"
                android:layout_width="121dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:background="@drawable/corner1"
                android:layout_weight="0.60"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_milk_quantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" Lts."
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:gravity="right"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="13dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            >
            <TextView

            android:id="@+id/btn_prodc_submit"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_sub_txt_size"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_layout_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/btnbackground"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolour"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: For getting values from database Internet is not required because of Internet it will not crash..... What error you are getting and where

Comment: @Rudresh he is getting from MySql (I suppose in server side), not from SQLite (phone)

Comment: yes. I getting the values from MySQL Database. if internet is not present the app crashes.

Comment: @vinodhkumar could you put the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Thank you @Joacher. the error occurred at    shiftid=(getShiftid(position));

Comment: Can u post the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I think should try something like that to show the default values if no internet, else get the values of the sql

```
if(cd.isConnectingToInternet()){
     prodropdown();
}else{
     //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
     List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
     spinnerArray.add("default value 1");
     spinnerArray.add("default value 2");
     spinnerArray.add("default value 3");

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

     spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I tried. But it not working. error occurred at @ Onitemclicklisterner

Comment: Could you put the code in the line that have the error?

Comment: Ok sir, I got the solution. Thank you.